# Existence of $\lim_{(x,y,z)\to(0,0,0)}\frac{\ln(1+x^2y^4z^6)}{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{\alpha+\frac{1}{2}}}$ for some $\alpha$.

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

Hy guys!

for which values of $\alpha\in\mathbb R$ does this limit exists? 
$$\lim_{(x,y,z)\to(0,0,0)}\frac{\ln(1+x^2y^4z^6)}{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{\alpha+\frac{1}{2}}}$$

I know that for all $\alpha\leq-\frac{1}{2}$ the limit exists, but how can I argue to prove (or disprove) that this limit exists for $\alpha>-\frac{1}{2}$?

Comment: The bound $\ln(1+x) ≤ x$ tells you that the limit exists for $\alpha ≤ \frac{1}{2}$; of course the limit does not exist for all positive value of $\alpha$. Take for example $x = y = z$ and $\alpha > 5.5$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We use [spherical coordinate system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system) for solving this limit. In the spherical coordinate system we suppose that
$$
\begin{array}{l}
x=r\,\sin(\theta)\,\cos(\phi)\\
y=r\,\sin(\theta)\,\sin(\phi)\\\tag{1}
z=r\, \cos(\theta)
\end{array}
$$
and the relation between $x$,$y$ and z is as follows 
$$
x^2+y^2+z^2=r^2\tag{2}
$$

If we substitute the values of  $x$,$y$ and z by $(1)$ when $r$ tends to zero and the value of limit exist and be independent of $\theta$and $\phi$, we say the limit exists and in the other cases we conclude that the limit dose not exist. So by using $(1)$ and $(2)$, we have 
$$
\lim_{(x,y,z)\to(0,0,0)}\frac{\ln(1+x^2y^4z^6)}{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{\alpha+\frac{1}{2}}}=
\lim_{r\to 0}\frac{\ln(1+{(r\,\sin(\theta)\,\cos(\phi))}^2\,{(r\,\sin(\theta)\,\sin(\phi))}^4\,{(r\, \cos(\theta))}^6)}{(r^2)^{\alpha+\frac{1}{2}}}
$$
$$
=\lim_{r\to 0}\frac{ln(1+r^{12}\,\sin(\theta)^{12}\,\cos(\phi)^{12})}{r^{2\alpha+1}}=\lim_{r\to 0} \frac{ln(1)}{r^{2\alpha+1}}\tag{3}
$$
In $(3)$ we use from this fact that limit of zero at the bounded functions is zero. The limit $(3)$ exist if $2\alpha+1\leq0$ or $\alpha\leq -\frac{1}{2}$ and for $\alpha> -\frac{1}{2}$ dose not exist.

I hope you find it useful.

Comment: that was really useful! what a beautiful answer!! thanks a lot @amin235!!

Comment: Your welcome! notice that if your limit is just based on the $x$ and $y$ when tend to zero use [Polar_coordinate_system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system). In fact the best tool for solving the limit with more than one variable are  spherical and polar system.

Comment: Your last result does have a limit, since $ln (1)$ is zero and every component is zero, so the limit is zero. Therefore I think the last equality is false.

Comment: @Cuteboy if $\alpha> -\frac{1}{2}$ then the limit is $\frac{0}{0}$ and we can prove by hospital rule, the limit dose not exist but if $\alpha\leq -\frac{1}{2}$ then the limit is $0 \times 0$ and the limit is exist and zero. Notice that you are right that $\ln(1)=0$ but is not absolute  zero, i mean it is $0^+$ or $0^-$ and not zero. if we had $\lbrack \ln(1) \rbrack$, then your comment was true. I hope you got it what i mean. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: @Amin235 you can not do that mathematically, there is no definition of so called "absolute zero". From your last expression one can only understand that the limit is always zero, no matter what $\alpha$ is, and I have no idea what you mean by $[\ln 1]$, since $\ln 1$ has exact the value $0$. I agree with your part until the last equality, and you can apply the L'hopital rule to the second last expression, but not the last one, and this requires some techniques.

Comment: @Cuteboy I used $\lbrack \ln(1) \rbrack$ to show [Floor and ceiling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions) of $\ln 1$. Please notice that we do not have $\ln 1$ in the numerator  of a fraction. In fact, we have $\ln(1\pm\epsilon)$ where $\epsilon$ is a small number. In the other words, $r^{12}\,\sin(\theta)^{12}\,\cos(\phi)^{12}$, is not absolute zero because $r$ tends to zero.

Comment: @Cuteboy For example, consider $\lim_{x\to 0}{\frac {\ln  \left( 1-x \right) }{x}}$ by hospital rule we can see that the result is $-1$ but we can check that $\lim_{x\to 0}{\frac {\lfloor\ln  \left( 1-x \right)\rfloor}{x}}=0$. If you would like we can continue our discussion in chat room of mathstack.

Comment: @Amin235 If you did not mean $\ln 1$ the exact $\ln 1$, then you should mention that in your answer... and one can not simply say $\ln (1\pm \epsilon)$, it is more complicated here, it is related to the decay ratio, you should give a more precise and rigorous description of such calculation. An example is $x/x^2$ and $x^2/x$, you see both numerator and denominator converge to zero as $x$ converges to zero, but they do have different limits. For me, your answer was somehow intuitive and did not really explain the case $\alpha>1/2$, and this would cause some probelms.

Comment: @Cuteboy I suggest to see second answer of [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/101580/using-epsilon-delta-approach-to-prove-that-lim-x-y-z-rightarrow-0-0?rq=1).